# No Available Video Device in SDL

Tags: c++, c, linux, sdl, sdl-2

The SDL-2 library I'm using was compiled from source.

Whenever I try to run any program that uses SDL-2 on X11, I am given this error:

```
SDL_Init Error: No available video device
```

I am running these programs through the command line on Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia.

Here's the `./configure` summary:

```
SDL2 Configure Summary:
Building Shared Libraries
Building Static Libraries
Enabled modules : atomic audio video render events joystick haptic sensor power filesystem threads timers file loadso cpuinfo assembly
Assembly Math   : mmx 3dnow sse sse2 sse3
Audio drivers   : disk dummy oss
Video drivers   : dummy opengl_es2 vulkan
Input drivers   : linuxev linuxkd
Using libsamplerate : NO
Using libudev       : NO
Using dbus          : NO
Using ime           : YES
Using ibus          : NO
Using fcitx         : NO
```

Comment: I had a similar problem when I didn't have X11 dev package installed. Besides, why compile SDL2 from source?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your SDL build is missing the X11 backend.

Mint looks sufficiently Debian-y that a `sudo apt build-dep libsdl2` ought to pull in the required `-dev` packages.  Then you can re-run `./configure` & rebuild/reinstall SDL.

Make sure to double-check that the `Video drivers` line in the `configure` summary has the backends you're interested in using.

If the `build-dep` method is too hand-wavy then [`docs/README-linux.md`](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/tip/docs/README-linux.md) has a (kinda old) itemized `-dev` package list:

> ```
> ================================================================================
> Build Dependencies
> ================================================================================
>     
> Ubuntu 13.04, all available features enabled:
>
> sudo apt-get install build-essential mercurial make cmake autoconf automake \
> libtool libasound2-dev libpulse-dev libaudio-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev \
> libxrandr-dev libxcursor-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxxf86vm-dev \
> libxss-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libesd0-dev libdbus-1-dev libudev-dev \
> libgles1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev libegl1-mesa-dev libibus-1.0-dev \
> fcitx-libs-dev libsamplerate0-dev libsndio-dev
>
> Ubuntu 16.04+ can also add "libwayland-dev libxkbcommon-dev wayland-protocols"
> to that command line for Wayland support.
>
> NOTES:
> - This includes all the audio targets except arts, because Ubuntu pulled the 
>   artsc0-dev package, but in theory SDL still supports it.
> - libsamplerate0-dev lets SDL optionally link to libresamplerate at runtime
>   for higher-quality audio resampling. SDL will work without it if the library
>   is missing, so it's safe to build in support even if the end user doesn't
>   have this library installed.
> - DirectFB isn't included because the configure script (currently) fails to find
>   it at all. You can do "sudo apt-get install libdirectfb-dev" and fix the 
>   configure script to include DirectFB support. Send patches.  :)
> ```

Comment: The programs are running without error now. Thank you @genpfault!